# HTML tags added to jQuery Code display undefined on web page

Tags: jquery, json

I'm using jQuery to retrieve specific data from a JSON txt file and display it on a webpage. The data is displayed on the page as expected, but needs to be formatted with HTML/CSS. When I add HTML tags like p or div, "undefined" is displayed several times on the page. This is probably something very simple I'm overlooking, but so far all the suggestions I've tried from other posts have not worked. I'm using jquery-1.9.1.min and this is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('cache/bitly-click-rate.txt', function(data){
       $.each(data, function(index, item){
               $('#bitly-click-rate').append('<p>' + item.phrase + '</p><p>' + item.rate + '</p>');
      });
    })
 })
```

Here is a screenshot of what is displayed on the webpage:
[image]

I've checked the JSON code and it is valid. Here is the JSON code though, if it helps:

```
{"status_code": 200, "data": {"phrase": "obama", "rate": 0.062096999999999999, "lag": 5, "time": 1360459793}, "status_txt": "OK"}
```

I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm missing here... Thanks in advance for the help.

**Update:**
Thanks to everyone for the fast responses. I updated the jQuery code because the problem seems to be because the returned JSON data is a single object and not an array. The jQuery code I was using is for a JSON array. I've updated the jQuery code based on Vlad's answer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('cache/bitly-click-rate.txt', function(data) {
              $('#bitly-click-rate').append('<p> Phrase: ' + data.phrase + '</p>' + '<p> Rate: ' + data.rate + '</p>');
    });
});
```

The data is still being displayed as undefined on the webpage, here is a screenshot:
[image]

It seems to me the above code should work. I've been researching, but so far most of the code suggestions are for JSON arrays. Please let me know if you have any ideas as to why the updated code isn't working. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post what the JSON looks like in this case? Are you sure the 1st and 3rd object actually have the `phrase` and `rate` properties?

Comment: Hi Vlad... I've edited the post to include the JSON code. The properties are in there. Thanks!

Comment: Please see my edit - since your JSON object has a property called `data` and you pass the variable `data` into the AJAX callback, things get confusing. I renamed the result to `result` and added the correct path to the `data` property in the result.

Comment: The JSON data is being displayed correctly now. Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your returned JSON data is a single object and not an array:

```
{"status_code": 200, "data": {"phrase": "obama", "rate": 0.062096999999999999, "lag": 5, "time": 1360459793}, "status_txt": "OK"}
```

So there is no need to use `each` in this case. You can just access properties directly:

```
$.getJSON('cache/bitly-click-rate.txt', function(result){
    $('#bitly-click-rate').append('<p>' + result.data.phrase + '</p><p>' + result.data.rate + '</p>');
})
```

If your JSON had an array of items, like so:

```
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "data": {
        "phrases": [
            {
                "phrase1": "obama",
                "rate": 0.062097,
                "lag": 5,
                "time": 1360459793
            },
            {
                "phrase2": "clinton",
                "rate": 0.062097,
                "lag": 5,
                "time": 1360459793
            }
        ]
    },
    "status_txt": "OK"
}
```

Only then would you have something to iterate over:

```
$.getJSON('cache/bitly-click-rate.txt', function(result){
    $.each(result.data.phrases, function(index, item){
        $('#bitly-click-rate').append('<p>' + item.phrase + '</p><p>' + item.rate + '</p>');
    });
})
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `data.data.phrase` as the object containing the property `phrase` is at its child's (which, to add some confusion is named `data`) level?

Comment: @FloydPink, you're right - I've updated the code to reflect that. Definitely confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('cache/bitly-click-rate.txt', function(data){
       $.each(data.data, function(index, item){
               $('#bitly-click-rate').append('<p>' + item.phrase + '</p><p>' + item.rate + '</p>');
      });
    })
 })
```

Because the object that you're interested in displaying is (I'm guessing) not the top level object in the callback (`data`), but instead the property named `data` in it.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently iterating over the returned JSON data element by element. The first element is:

```
data.status_code
```

Which has a value of 200. And 200.phrase doesn't make sense, so it's undefined.